# How to extract number from character string?

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    > dns1
               variant_id         gene_id pval_nominal
21821  chr1_165656237_T_C_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21822 chr1_165659346_C_CA_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21823  chr1_165659350_A_G_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21824  chr1_165659415_A_G_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21825  chr1_165660430_T_C_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21826  chr1_165661135_T_G_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21827  chr1_165661238_C_T_b38 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
...
```

I would like to remove all characters from the 2nd column (variant_id) and to extract just the second number, to look like this:

```
165656237
165659346
165659350
165659415
165660430
165661135
165661238
...
```

I tried this:

```
dns1$variant_id <- gsub('[^0-9.]', '', dns1$variant_id)
```

but with the above command I am getting this:

```
> dns1
      variant_id         gene_id pval_nominal
21821    116565623738 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21822    116565934638 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21823    116565935038 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
21824    116565941538 ENSG00000143149  1.24119e-05
...
```

So this matches all numbers in *variant_id* column, and I would need to get 16565623738 instead of 116565623738. So the question is how to match in this 2nd column just the 2nd number?

Comment: When I run `gsub('_(.*)','', 'chr1_165656237_T_C_b38')` I get `"chr1"`. That's not what you want, but I'm not getting the result you report.

Comment: Make sure you share a `dput()` of your data, or something else we can copy/paste into R. knowing exactly whats in your data and how it's stored is important. Also, make sure this is reproducible. I too get something different when running the code. There must be something you are leaving out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

```
dns1$variant_id <- sub('^[^_]*_(\\d+).*', '\\1', dns1$variant_id)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ckBAfk/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The `sub` function will only perform a single search and replace operation on each string, and the `\1` backreference in the replacement will put back the contents in Group 1.

[Online R demo](https://ideone.com/9ziOLb):

```
variant_id <- c("chr1_165656237_T_C_b38", "chr1_165659346_C_CA_b38")
dns1 <- data.frame(variant_id)
dns1$variant_id <- sub('^[^_]*_(\\d+).*', '\\1', dns1$variant_id)
dns1
##=> variant_id
## 1  165656237
## 2  165659346
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can catch the digits as follows:

```
gsub(".*?_([[:digit:]]+)_.*", "\\1", dns1$variant_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)

df <-
  data.frame(variant_id = c("chr1_165656237_T_C_b38",
                            "chr1_165659346_C_CA_b38",
                            "chr1_165659350_A_G_b38",
                            "chr1_165659415_A_G_b38",
                            "chr1_165660430_T_C_b38",
                            "chr1_165661135_T_G_b38",
                            "chr1_165661238_C_T_b38"))

df$variant_id_extract <-
  str_replace(df$variant_id, "^.+_(\\d+)_.+$", "\\1")

df
#>                variant_id variant_id_extract
#> 1  chr1_165656237_T_C_b38          165656237
#> 2 chr1_165659346_C_CA_b38          165659346
#> 3  chr1_165659350_A_G_b38          165659350
#> 4  chr1_165659415_A_G_b38          165659415
#> 5  chr1_165660430_T_C_b38          165660430
#> 6  chr1_165661135_T_G_b38          165661135
#> 7  chr1_165661238_C_T_b38          165661238
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super hacky solution which uses both gsub and str_replace (from stringr). I'm sure there are better solutions, and this requires that variant_id always begins `chr1_`, which may not be fair.

```
dns1$variant_id <- gsub('_(.*)','', str_replace(dns1$variant_id, 'chr1_',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
dns$variant_id_new <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(dns$variant_id), "_"), unlist)[2,]
```

Logically, this first splits all strings in `variant_id` by the `_`. The `sapply(,unlist)` turns this into a matrix, where we take the second row (for the second variable).

Answer (score 0):

Using *utils::strcapture* we can extract all parts of the variant ID, including the genomic position.

```
# example input
x <- c("chr1_165656237_T_C_b38", "chr1_165659346_C_CA_b38")

# get pattern for each part
pattern <- "(.*?)_([[:digit:]]+)_([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)_(b[0-9]+)"

# empty dataframe with columns to match after split
proto <- data.frame(chrom = character(), position = integer(), 
                    allele1 = character(), allele2 = character(), build = character())

# extract
strcapture(pattern, x, proto)
#   chrom  position allele1 allele2 build
# 1  chr1 165656237       T       C   b38
# 2  chr1 165659346       C      CA   b38
```